# SurfaceImageSource and IDXGISurface BackBuffer size mismatch

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, directx, windows-8.1, sharpdx

I’m running into an odd problem where the IDXGISurface BackBuffer description doesn’t match the size of the SurfaceImageSource that created it. I can’t find any documentation on why this would be the case, but I’m seeing subtle variances (eg: 1366x768 becomes 1376x768, 2560x1440 becomes 2592x1440 and so on).

I have the source for an isolated repro here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=16E5F6030DCB8991!25573&authkey=!AF0Y3h0-ufLPubs&ithint=file%2c.zip

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. When using SurfaceImageSource, the DXGI surface you get is often a reference to an [atlased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) surface. XAML does this to improve performance and reduce memory overhead (especially for apps that use many small SurfaceImageSource elements).

Applications are expected to render into a subset of this region based on the returned `offset` value of [BeginDraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Also note that you should never cache this value or the `IDXGISurface*` since XAML may give you a different offset or atlas on subsequent calls to BeginDraw.

In your case since you only have one SurfaceImageSource, the atlas usually roughly matches the requested size.  However, if you had two SurfaceImageSource objects each 1366x768, it's likely you would get back a single `IDXGISurface` that is 1376x1536, where calling BeginDraw for one returns (0,0) and BeginDraw for the other returns (0,768). Those points serve as the origin at which you should draw into the surface.

One other thing - considering the sizes you've tried, it looks like you're trying to create a full-screen SurfaceImageSource.  Depending on the scenario, [SwapChainPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn252834) might be more appropriate, and actually gives you a properly buffered swap chain.

Comment: Thanks, this is great information! I do have a full-screen SurfaceImageSource, but on a page that also contains XAML components, which unfortunately seems to rule out using a SwapChainPanel.

Comment: @GabrielIsenberg That should work just fine - you should be able to use SwapChainPanel on the same page as other elements.

Comment: Thanks again! Your comment got me on the right track. I had investigated using a SwapChainBackgroundPanel, not a SwapChainPanel as you had suggested. I'm using SharpDX, and the  ISwapChainPanelNative interface wasn't present in the nuget package.   I was able to get the effect I wanted after updating to a pre-release build that contained ISwapChainPanelNative.

Comment: As an aside, where did you learn about the SurfaceImageSource atlasing? I didn't see any notes about that behavior anywhere in the docs I went over. Curious what resource could have steered me in the right direction.

Comment: @GabrielIsenberg There are a few articles on DirectX/XAML interop. [This one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx#SurfaceImageSource) in particular describes how to use SurfaceImageSource. The offset parameter (step 4) implies atlasing of some sort, especially when you use multiple objects and see the correlation of the offsets.